# Xcode and Git installation on MacOSX Mountain Lion

Tags: xcode, macos, git, shell, installation

I just installed Mountain Lion and Xcode, so under `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin` I found the Git directory

But when I use Git commands in the shell terminal it **returns error of command not found**. Any suggestions? I have many Git repos on my mac, so I would like to reuse them without checking them out again :/

Comment: Another alternative is to install Git via [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/). You then need to adjust the `$PATH` environment variable to prioritize the custom installation over the one from Xcode. This will allow to **update Git at any time**. Also you avoid touching Apple's setup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to install the command line tools (see Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads) or you can download it from the [Apple Developer Download site](https://developer.apple.com/downloads).

Answer (score 3):

First of all, installing the Xcode Command Line tools is probably not what you want. See this post for more information:

http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/you-dont-need-the-xcode-command-line-tools/

You want to set up symbolic links or aliases that point to the versions of git (and svn etc.) that exist inside Xcode.app. This will cause you to automatically get newer versions when Xcode updates through the app store. Installing the command line tools will only confuse matters because you will end up with multiple versions of git lying around, and you will have to manually update the command line tools.

The commands you will need are:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app # tells 'xcrun' where to look
```

And then in your shell profile, for example `.bash_profile`:

```
alias git='xcrun git' # use 'xcrun' to locate the git binary
```

Now running 'git' from the terminal will use the latest version inside Xcode.app.

Comment: So the command line tools aren't for running on the command line?

Comment: The command line tools are a standalone version of what exists in Xcode.app. It is far more maintainable to use 'xcrun' as apple suggests: "Before installing, note that from within Terminal you can use the XCRUN tool to launch compilers and other tools embedded within the Xcode application. Use the XCODE-SELECT tool to define which version of Xcode is active.  Type "man xcrun" from within Terminal to find out more."

Comment: So it's a simple matter of setting `CC=xcrun clang` `LD=xcrun ld` `AR=xcrun ar` before running `make`?  Or is that `xcrun make`?  That is complete nonsense.

Comment: You can also add `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/` to your PATH environment variable. The idea is to use the tools inside Xcode.app so you get automatic updates and don't have multiple versions of everything.

Comment: Xcode updates the command line tools for you, and I don't really care about multiple versions of everything; it's not important.  The main thing is that life is simple.

Comment: thx to Mike too, is anyway good to listen to other solutions! ;) and obviously thx to trojanfoe too