# xCode Source (Version) Control - I committed to a date in the future - how do I delete the commit or change the date?

Tags: ios, xcode, git, date, version-control

While testing in xCode, I changed my computer system time. At some point, I forgot to change it back and performed a commit. Now the commit has a future date, and I don't want that to wreak havoc on my source control. I do not use GitHub outside of the project (I am learning Github now). Is there any way within xCode to either change the date of that last commit, or delete the commit altogether?

Answer (score 0):

It is best to [redo your last commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/927386/6309) through git comamnd-line, and then refresh your XCode project.

```
git reset --soft "HEAD^"
$ edit
$ git add ....
$ git commit -c ORIG_HEAD
```

Comment: thanks. You know I am not familiar with how to do that - is it through xCode? Would you mind sharing the steps?

Comment: @JPK You need to go to the root folder of your project (where you can see a .git subfolder) and type the command I mention. Make sure you have git installed in addition of XCode: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12842165/6309 and http://vandadnp.wordpress.com/2012/04/06/git-from-command-line-after-installing-xcode-on-os-x-lion/.